Cant repair chrome remote desktop host on ubuntu 24.04
My connection to Ubuntu 24.04 VM recently got broke so I decided to reinstall the host app and reregister it, but I keep failing. I suspect that host ID might not get purged when installing new crd host package
The steps I’m taking are:
1.       On Ubuntu – I removed “This device” from connection list
https://i.imgur.com/TVLiQQ2.png
2.       Sudo apt remove chrome-remote-desktop (and purged it also)
3.       Restarted the Ubuntu VM
4.       Downloaded crd package as instruction for g.co/headless suggested
https://i.imgur.com/1rqrIWv.png
5.       Installed the package (looks good)
https://i.imgur.com/eXT265s.png
6.       On my Windows laptop I generate the auth script and send it to Ubuntu VM
https://i.imgur.com/4F1T7V0.png
7.       On Ubuntu VM I get the script and execute it with results:
https://i.imgur.com/yy8Ojhs.png
8.       On my Windows laptop I see option to connect to Ubuntu VM, but PIN is wrong
https://i.imgur.com/HA7jM5x.png
The only thing I see is that host ID that exists and I’m not 100% is it removed.
Maybe connection attempt tries to come to old remote desktop that doesn’t exist anymore?
I also tried to install older version as suggested here: Chrome Remote Desktop in 24.04
Anyone got such issue and solved it?
